# Develop app specifically for my custom android ROM

Tags: android

I have a custom ROM with some modified classes and a few new ones, and I need to develop an app which uses this modified version of the android API. How can i achieve that? In other words, how can i import new classes (and use new methods in the old classes) from the custom ROM in my app development environment (eclipse and android sdk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 options to do this:

-> Find out the jar to substitute in the sdk platform in use, instead of making the jar file myself:

> out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar

(Did not tested this one, the first worked fine for me)

-> Do the following steps to build the sdk:
 1. Use `repo init -g all ; repo sync` to get some dependencies in the aosp root directory;
 2. `source build/envsetup.sh`;
 3. `lunch sdk-eng`;
 4. `make sdk` A directory will be created somewhere inside "out" directory, with a name like "android-sdk_eng.USERNAME_linux-x86";
 5. In Eclipse: Preferences > Android, select SDK Location and point to the new directory created;

You can copy the directory to somewhere else before point eclipse to it.

Some links to the source of that information: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/DpKnrpLMBgI/hTfF0GvUWU8J) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/ZCc6OfhNhNk/R8USGGDoYq0J)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse, you can achieve that by creating a jar of all the android framework classes, including your new classes, than add it as a library in your project.

The ADT plugin will automatically add it to the "*Android Dependencies*" which is exported with your APK. But you propbably don't want to include it in your final APK.

So, in your project's properties window, go into "*Java Build Path*", then select the tab "*Order and Export*", then uncheck the "*Android Dependencies*", and check all libraries that you may be using in your app that was in the group and you want exported.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i found better ways to do it. I just posted it in another answer!